# Hearing Bell sounds - What does the Bible say about bells?

Tags: symbolism, spirituality

Recently I have heard many bell sounds during times of heavy spiritual warfare & physical troubles. I know i'm not crazy because I've had relatives and friends hear them as-well. They come from multiple directions and have been heard at multiple locations.

What is the biblical significance of bells and what symbolism does it carry?

Comment: Both [Pastoral Advice Questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/255) and verse identification questions are off-topic. Ref: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4199) and ["Biblical basis" vs "what the Bible says about a subject"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3958)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Bible mentions bells only in Exodus (chapters 28 and 39), where they formed part of the decoration of the robes of the Priests, and in Zechariah (chapter 14), where in the last verse it proclaims that the bells on horses will be engraved with "Holy is the Lord".

Bell sounds can travel quite a long distance, so that the sounds you are hearing may not necessarily be from your house. I once heard quite a delightful wind chime on the breeze, and upon exploration found that the chime was a couple of blocks away. Another thing to consider is that the sound may not be coming from an actual bell, but rather another piece of metal which is free to vibrate when struck.

Any spiritual significance of any bell comes from the hearer of the bell, rather than the bell itself. A case in point is bells rung on Sunday morning, and other times of the week. To some, the bells are calls to prayer, and sometimes for some people, a bell at a specific time is a call to a specific prayer. To others hearing the same sounds, the bells simply denote the time of day, and to still others, they sometimes are only a nuisance to be endured.